# USB Host and Device communication happen in the same controller preferably Pic controller

Tags: usb, usb-device, usb-host

Working on new project, which requires- 1st port is for HOST function with Type A connector and 2nd is for Device function with Type B connector & not support USB host port and device port at the same time. how that can be design with PIC controller.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. While you think about fixing that, remember that [shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) is off-topic.

Comment: Please try making your question more clear and as @brhans mentions; shopping questions are off topic and thereby not allowed here on electronics stack exchange.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve that with some PIC32 devices which have 2 USB ports.

The Microchip Harmony stack, however, is not properly tested/working (despite what advertized) when working with both ports at the same time in host/device configuration.

You may need to implement your own USB stack or use some that are available online.

In my case, I used Harmony stack for the USB Host side and a stack found online for the USB Device side.

The port type is only related to what USB connector you choose.

Comment: we will not connect at time. how to configure own USB stack?., can you tell schematically how it can be connected.

Answer (score -1):

You may use NXP's LPC17XX or LPC18XX devices.

They are ARM based micro controllers.

There are many examples for both USB host and device modes. Some examples were written from Keil.

I used USB host and device of LPC2388 and LPC1778 and I got no problems at all.

I was able to read and write flash drives.

I was able to attach my board, as a hard drive, to my PC.

Comment: ., i am using the PIC32 controller., can not implement this in PIC32 controller? and  if yes, let me know - how schematically prove or connection else why can not able to implement?

Comment: Go to Microchip's site. I use NXP's microcontroller, sorry.

Comment: Thank you for your support